# sha256() output

Tags: solidity, hash, hash-algorithm

I used `sha256()` hash of a string and I got the following result
`0x0de69f56365c10550d05e65ae8229dd0686f7894a807830daec8caa879731f4d` for string `Hello World2`. Now I want to find out leading byte from the output of sha256() which is 'od' in this case.As the return type of `sha256()` is `bytes32` how to read the leading bytes from the output.
Here is the code I used to get `sha256()` of a string.

```
contract TestIntToString {
  function getSha256(string str) external pure returns (bytes32) {
    bytes32 hash = sha256(abi.encodePacked(str));

    return hash;
    //string y    = hash;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `sha256()` function outputs a `bytes32`, which is is a [fixed-size byte array](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#fixed-size-byte-arrays) you can easily access the leading byte of the hash, simply by returning `hash[0]`.

Comment: How to check whether leading byte is all zeros.

Comment: by returning hash[0] which is bytes1 it gives the output like this 0xod but I want only od

Comment: Well, they are the same number, it is just a question of string representation.

Comment: can you answer my comment1?

Comment: Oh, yeah! regarding your first question: hash[0] == byte(0) as well as hash[0] == 0 will do the job.

Comment: Hey can you say this-  I want to get all strings with nonces such that their leading bytes is 0 from sha256() output

Comment: I guess you can not get all such strings in any feasible time. This looks quite a computationally heavy task. You would essentially need to iterate through the domain of sha256, which is infinite, since any string with arbitrary length can be the input of a hash function :P

Comment: What about first 100 strings+nonce